# How do I pivot time-series data to show sum/count per month

Tags: r, time-series, pivot

I have a data set that contains a row identifying every time a patient experiences a symptom. It includes an identifier, the overarching symptom category (disease), the symptom experienced, and the date it was experienced. I would like to pivot this data to count how many times each unique set of disease/symptom occurred in each given month. I am sure the solution exists here on StackOverflow and I have looked but I have not found anything that gets me to where it needs to be. I have provided a sample data set as well as my expected output, obviously created manually.

```
id <- c(sprintf("A%03d", 1:3), sprintf("B%03d", 1:5))
c("disease", "symptom", "date")
x <- c(rep("bronchitis", 3), rep("flu", 5))
y <- c(rep("coughing", 2), "congestion", rep("fever", 3), "aches", "fatigue")
z <- as.factor(c("Jan 27, 2019", "Jan 26, 2019", "Dec 27, 2018", "Dec 03, 
2018", "Dec 18, 2018", "Nov 14, 2018", "Nov 21, 2018", "Jan 15, 2019"))
df <- data.frame("id" = id, "disease" = x, "symptom" = y, "date" = z)
df

a <- c(rep("bronchitis", 2), rep("flu", 3))
b <- c("cough", "congestion", "fever", "aches", "fatigue")
c <- c(0,0,1,1,0)
d <- c(0,1,2,0,0)
e <- c(2, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df2 <- data.frame("disease" = a, "symptom" = b, "Nov" = c, "Dec" = d, "Jan" = e)
```

df is the original data set,
df2 is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exact order of dates, you could do:

```
df %>%
  count(disease,
        symptom,
        date = factor(format(as.Date(date, "%b%d,%Y"),"%b-%Y"),
                      levels = apply(expand.grid(month.abb, 1950:2050), 1, paste, collapse ="-"))) %>%
  spread(date, n, fill = 0)
```

This would correspond to your desired output, however it would keep the year in the names (as you order it from `Nov` until `Jan`, suggesting the year should also play a part in ordering & also grouping):

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  disease    symptom    `Nov-2018` `Dec-2018` `Jan-2019`
  <fct>      <fct>           <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 bronchitis congestion          0          1          0
2 bronchitis coughing            0          0          2
3 flu        aches               1          0          0
4 flu        fatigue             0          0          1
5 flu        fever               1          2          0
```

If the year is not desired in the column names, you can just `setNames` at the end:

```
df %>%
  count(disease,
        symptom,
        date = factor(format(as.Date(date, "%b%d,%Y"),"%b-%Y"),
                      levels = apply(expand.grid(month.abb, 1950:2050), 1, paste, collapse ="-"))) %>%
  spread(date, n, fill = 0) %>%
  setNames(., sub("-.*", "", names(.)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  disease    symptom      Nov   Dec   Jan
  <fct>      <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 bronchitis congestion     0     1     0
2 bronchitis coughing       0     0     2
3 flu        aches          1     0     0
4 flu        fatigue        0     0     1
5 flu        fever          1     2     0
```

Comment: Thank you @arg0naut! This is excellent and is really what I was looking for. Something that scales. Obviously this this only a small sample size data set, the actual data set will contain decades worth of data and I'd like to maintain the years for a time-series analysis. I should have been more clear about that in the original description.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that here I presumed you won't be analyzing anything before 1950 or after 2050, but if this is not the case, `1950:2050` should be adapted to that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact order of df2, but:

```
> df %>% 
  mutate(date = substr(df$date, 1, 3)) %>% 
  group_by(disease, symptom, date) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  spread(date, n, fill = 0)


   disease     symptom Dec Jan Nov 
bronchitis  congestion  1   0   0
bronchitis    coughing  0   2   0
       flu       aches  0   0   1
       flu     fatigue  0   1   0
       flu       fever  2   0   1
```

Comment: `date = factor(substr(df$date, 1, 3), levels=month.abb)` fixes the issue with the column order. @Joe Stoica